# How to show dialog gauge for wget?

Tags: linux, shell, dialog

I want to display the progress of `wget` using dialog box(`gauge`).

I found one solution [on this site](http://www.dawoodfall.net/scripts/bash/wget-dialog-example) but it is not showing upto 100 percent. After 90 percent, the dialog freezes/stops and the code exits.

Is there any way to show dialog gauge for wget?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686464/howto-show-wget-progress-bar-only may be of interest if you haven't seen it already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
URL="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Pleiades_large.jpg"
wget "$URL" 2>&1 | \
 stdbuf -o0 awk '/[.] +[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?%/ { print substr($0,63,3) }' | \
 dialog --gauge "Download Test" 10 100
```

Comment: I wonder about the cases where this might not produce a number.  But from my tests character 63-65 is the current percent.

Comment: Thanks Derek. I tried out your solution with some larger files. But the progress is not shown as soon as the download starts. It shows 0% for a while, and then, suddenly move to 50%, and then, to 100%. Did you face the same issue? Is there anything to be added/modified to this solution?

Comment: I think it depends on the size of the file being downloaded.

Comment: Also, what do you mean a while?  The above might not work very well for small files on a slow connection.  Look at --progress in wget's man page to understand why.  Each dot is 1k for default.

Comment: The delay you are seeing is the sequence of numbers being buffered in the pipe.  Disable buffering as follows:  wget "$URL" 2>&1 | stdbuf -o0 awk …etc