# How do I show progress percentage when copying files in powershell form?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm building a powershell GUI to back up profile folders. All works well, except I can't figure out how to accurately show a progress percentage for each folder.

Here's what I currently have...

```
    $dir = "Drive letter of choice" (ex. "C:")
    $user = "C:\Users\username"
    $userfolder = "username"

    $Files = Get-ChildItem -Path "$User\Documents\*" -Recurse

    $i=0

    ForEach ($File in $Files) {

        $i++
        [int]$pct = ($i/$Files.count)*100
        Copy-Item "$User\Documents\$File" "$dir\Backups\$UserFolder\Documents\" -Recurse
        $Status_Label.Text = "Backing Up Documents... $($pct)%"
        $GUI.Refresh()

        start-sleep -Milliseconds 100

    } # End ForEach
```

Based on a side-by-side compare it looks to copy all the folders/files just fine, but the percentage is way off. In the case of the Documents folder example above the file copy is done by the time it hits 15-20%. The rest are "source file can't be found" errors. It's looking for files in the main folder (Documents, Pictures, etc) that are actually in sub-folders.

I can see why it would be looking in the main Documents folder since the source of `Copy-Item` is the root folder, but why does it copy everything correctly into their sub-folders and then go back and complain about all those sub-files?

(This also needs to work in Windows 7)

Thanks!

Comment: Your current solution only shows completion based on # of files, not on data transferred.

Comment: That makes sense. Most of what I've been finding about progress indicators talks about Write-Progress, which I don't think I can use because that just shows it in the console window (correct?). It's been tough to find anything else.

Comment: `Write-Progress` will essentially do the same thing you're doing, just shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use *gauge* in *dialog boxes* (Something like: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784101/how-to-show-dialog-gauge-for-wget), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77253/bash-console-progress-dialog-with-command-output), [3](http://aurelio.net/shell/dialog/#copiagauge) (this one is in portuguese, but has a good code sample))

But I'm not sure about Windows.

Comment: Thanks, but Linux Bash and Powershell don't mix.